# Limiting a number so that It can only loop within a certain range?

Tags: loops, numbers, range, limits

I am looking for a way to make a number that I have only map to values in a certain range.

For example if I have the number -7 and I want to make sure that, whatever number I add or subtract from it the result will always be between 0 and 10 for example.

I know I can limit a number to only be between 0 and x by % dividing that number to x like so:

```
(myNumber + anotherNumber) % x
```

this will always give me a result between 0 and x.

The problem is this doesn't work if the result is a negative number.

Example :

```
myNumber = 4
secondNumber = -7
x = 6;
myNumber + anotherNumber = -3
(myNumber + anotherNumber) % 6 gives me 0
```

What I want to get is if I have 4 and then add -7 to it, I should get 3.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: do the sum and while the result is negative add `secondNumber`, then do the modulo. In you case -3 < 0 => -3 + 6 = 3 => 3 % 6 = 3

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the result is negativ.  If so then 
Result :(-1) = positiv result